# How to use the library from .js to .ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I can't find how to use the library in .ts file, which is declared in the .js.
I have following situation:

1. I have app.js where i'm declaring axious
2. My other files are written in TypeScript, and in them i want to use axious

I've tried to declare axious as:

```
declare var axios: any;
```

But in this way, i'm loosing tips of IDE. The decription file is already exists with the library. Can it be merged to my .d.ts file?
How will i use:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app_ts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `tsc` to compile all the typescript files, and then just import them as regular js files :) let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @DakshMiglani, I can't compile .ts without the description of libraries. The compiler will return a TS2304 error. Or I don't understand you?